# Collision detection (tutorial: How to make a platform game like Super Mario Brothers)

Tags: sprite-kit

guys!

I am following this tutorial [How to make a platform game like Super Mario Brothers](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62049/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1) to create a simple platform game. In the tutorial, the character sprite's size is a about a size of a single tile, and collision detection is calculated for 8 surrounding tiles. I modified the sprite's size to be equal about 4 tiles (2x2) and calculate collisions with 12 surrounding tiles. It works fine for the bottom and right sprite's edges, but the left and upper edges a little bit overlap with an obstacle before collision occurs, that is obviously wrong.

I feel that I have some mistakes in there, but as I am quite new in Spritekit I cannot spot them. I would really appreciate if someone could help me with it. Thanks in advance.

Here is the update function for the character:

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)delta
{
CGPoint gravity = CGPointMake(0.0, -450.0);
CGPoint gravityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(gravity, delta);

CGPoint forwardMove = CGPointMake(800.0, 0.0);
CGPoint forwardMoveStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(forwardMove, delta);
CGPoint backwardMove = CGPointMake(-800.0, 0.0);
CGPoint backwardMoveStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(backwardMove, delta);

if (self.forwardMarch)
{
    self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, forwardMoveStep);
}
if (self.backwardMarch)
{
    self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, backwardMoveStep);
}

self.velocity = CGPointAdd(self.velocity, gravityStep);
self.velocity = CGPointMake(self.velocity.x * 0.9, self.velocity.y);

// setup minimum and maximum limits for the motion speed
CGPoint minMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, -450);
CGPoint maxMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

// forward motion
if (self.velocity.x >= 0)
{
    minMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, -450);
    maxMovement = CGPointMake(120.0, 250.0);
}
// backward motion
if (self.velocity.x < 0)
{
    minMovement = CGPointMake(-120.0, -450);
    maxMovement = CGPointMake(0.0, 250.0);
}
self.velocity = CGPointMake(Clamp(self.velocity.x, minMovement.x, maxMovement.x), Clamp(self.velocity.y, minMovement.y, maxMovement.y));

CGPoint velocityStep = CGPointMultiplyScalar(self.velocity, delta);
self.newPosition = CGPointAdd(self.position, velocityStep);
}
```

This function find the bounding box of the sprite

```
- (CGRect)collisionBoundingBox
{
CGPoint diff = CGPointSubtract(self.newPosition, self.position);

return CGRectOffset(self.frame, diff.x, diff.y);
}
```

And the function where I handle collisions

```
- (void)handleObstacleCollisionsForPlayer:(Player *)player forLayer:(TMXLayer *)layer
{
NSInteger indices[12] = {13, 14, 1, 2, 4, 8, 7, 11, 0, 3, 12, 15};
player.onGround = NO;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    NSInteger tileIndex = indices[i];

    CGRect playerRect = [player collisionBoundingBox];
    CGPoint playerCoord = [layer coordForPoint:player.newPosition];

    NSInteger tileColumn = tileIndex % 4;
    NSInteger tileRow = tileIndex / 4;
    CGPoint tileCoord = CGPointMake(playerCoord.x + (tileColumn - 1), playerCoord.y + (tileRow - 1));

    NSInteger gid = [self tileGIDAtTileCoord:tileCoord forLayer:layer];
    if (gid)
    {
        CGRect tileRect = [self tileRectFromTileCoords:tileCoord];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(playerRect, tileRect))
        {
            CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection(playerRect, tileRect);

            if (tileIndex == 13 || tileIndex == 14)
            {
                //tile is below
                player.newPosition = CGPointMake(player.newPosition.x, player.newPosition.y + intersection.size.height);
                player.velocity = CGPointMake(player.velocity.x, 0.0);
                player.onGround = YES;
            }
            else if (tileIndex == 1 || tileIndex == 2)
            {
                //tile is directly above
                player.newPosition = CGPointMake(player.newPosition.x, player.newPosition.y - intersection.size.height);
            }
            else if (tileIndex == 4 || tileIndex == 8)
            {
                //tile is left
                player.newPosition = CGPointMake(player.newPosition.x + intersection.size.width, player.newPosition.y);
            }
            else if (tileIndex == 7 || tileIndex == 11)
            {
                //tile is right
                player.newPosition = CGPointMake(player.newPosition.x - intersection.size.width, player.newPosition.y);
            }
        }
    }
}

player.position = player.newPosition;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use the built-in collision detection handler in sprite kit.

Answer (score 0):

inside your GameViewController.m enable debug physics mode

that will draw a thick outline around every box and give u exact information about collision tiles may  i think either your hero or tile sizes are differ than the tutorial you following

skView.showsPhysics= YES;